# html2pdf issue with page break (new page)

Tags: php, page-break, html2pdf

i have a problem with creating a page break in a loop using `html2pdf v4.03`.

I have tried:

```
$pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'de', true, 'UTF-8');
$output = "";     
for (...) {
$output = '<div style="page-break-after: always;">' . $i . '</div>';
}
$pdf->WriteHTML($output);
$pdf->Output('file.pdf', "D");
```

---

And also:

```
$pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'de', true, 'UTF-8');
$output = "";     
for (...) {
$output = '<div>' . $i . '</div><!--NewPage-->';
}
$pdf->WriteHTML($output);
$pdf->Output('file.pdf', "D");
```

---

I also tried:

```
<pagebreak/>
<?page-break>
```

(i found this here: [here](http://www.tufat.com/docs/html2ps/faq.html#explicit-break))

---

No solution is working.
Has anyone a idea how it can be done?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an unlimited number of new `page`s.

In this instance:

```
for (...) {
$output = '<page>' . $i . '</page>';
}
```

That should do the trick.